# Building a scalable efficiant messages table

Tags: database, postgresql

Im building a message system in PostgreSql where 2 people can message each other. I also want to be able to get a list of conversations with the last message as a preview (like whatsapp)

Idea 1. I started with this simple message table

```
| id | to | from | text | createdAt
```

"to" and "from" refer to the user ids.

I scrapped this after learning the query to get a list of conversations with the last message was too intensive for running every time a user goes on the messages tab.
Here it is

```
select *
from messages
join (select max( id ) as maxId from messages where "from" = ? or "to" = ? GROUP BY GREATEST( "to", "from" ), LEAST( "to", "from" )) latest
on messages.id=latest.maxId
order by id desc
```

And this is without joining the user table too.

Idea 2. I decided maybe a conversations table to group the messages

```
| id | user1 | user2 | lastMessage
```

lastMessage will be the message id, and the messages table will change to this

```
| id | convo | user | text | createdAt
```

To get a list of convos with their last message, it would be a simple join. But a downside is every time a message is sent, I will have to do 2 additional queries to update the lastMessage and also to check if the user is part of that convo.

I think the 2 extra queries outweigh the subqueries it has to do with the 1st idea

Im looking for the objectively best way to accomplish the 2 requirements with the least amount of queries/ sub queries while still being scalable and manageable

Comment: If you want it to be efficient, then use a **message queue** for messaging, not an RDBMS. Most databases are not efficient at pub/sub.

Comment: @BillKarwin Would you store messages in a queue? I was planning on using sockets, but I will still need to store them in a database to keep a record won't I?

Comment: You can store messages in a database, but notifying listeners that a new message exists is the costly part. There are message queue products that support [persistent queues](https://activemq.apache.org/persistence).

Comment: @BillKarwin ok noted, what would your personal choice for a queue be, over sockets. Ive used SQS and RabbitMQ before

Comment: Those are good. At my last job we used ActiveMQ and it was also really good. The choice also depends on how many queues you want (it's easy to create a large number of queues in RabbitMQ for instance), and which queue protocol you want to use in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can elaborate on your slow `SELECT` statement and do it like this:

```sql
WITH last_msg_per_user_and_chat AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON(m."from", m."to")
        m."id", m."from", m."to", m."text", m."createdAt"
    FROM messages m
    WHERE (m."from" = ? OR m."to" = ?)
    ORDER BY m."createdAt" DESC)
SELECT lm.*
FROM last_msg_per_user_and_chat lm
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM last_msg_per_user_and_chat lm2
    WHERE lm2."from" = lm."to"
        AND lm2."to" = lm."from"
        AND lm2."createdAt" > lm."createdAt"
)
```

If you now establish indexes on `("from", "to", "createdAt" DESC)` and `("to", "from", "createdAt" DESC)`, you query should perform not that bad.

Some other tips:

- Do not rely on the `id` when you want to sort by the time. Usually, this should be the same, but you cannot be sure. You have a dedicated field for the time, so you should use it.
- Do not use quoted identifiers in `PostgreSQL`, as you need to use the `"` everywhere. It is usually easier without doing this.
- You could organize your conversations as a table `conversation(id)` and make a m:n mapping between your users and the conversations in a table like `participant(id, user_id, conversation_id)`. This would also allow for group conversations.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I really like the group chat idea and I think i will do it that way, I read its faster to sort by id instead of a date, and since its auto increment i think id would be the smarter choice, if it is indeed faster

Comment: If you have appropriate indexes, it should be the same in speed (at least with ```PostgreSQL```). Relying on some additional meaning of the ```id``` is bad practice, thus I cannot recommend to do this. But anyways, do as you like